# How to evaluate the integral $\int_0^5 3x^2 dx $?

Tags: calculus

I found an expression that's 
$$\int_0^5 3x^2 dx $$
and I was wondering on how to do it, I need the steps so, I can actually learn not just get the answer

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know the power rule for evaluating integrals?

Comment: Showing us youre work would be helpful, but you'll have to find the antiderivative, and then evaluate and $x=5$ and then subtract the expression evaluated for $x=0$

Comment: Open up any calculus textbook to the section on integrals/integration and start reading :)

Comment: The fundamental theorem says: $\int\limits_a^b {\frac{{\operatorname{df} }}{{\operatorname{dx} }}} \operatorname{dx}  = f\left( b \right) - f\left( a \right)$.  So figure out the antiderivative of that function and evaluate as above.

Comment: Split the intervals in some pieces and start drawing rectangles.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

1. Find an anti-derivative of $f(x) = 3x^2$. Usually, the anti-derivative of $Ax^k$ will be $\frac{A}{k+1} x^{k+1}$ (except for $k=-1$). This can be checked by differentiation.
2. Once your anti-derivative $F(x)$ is ready you compute using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
   $$
   \int_a^b f(x) dx = \left. F(x) \right|_a^b = F(b) - F(a).
   $$

Can you finish the problem?

Comment: \*_an_ antiderivative, not _the_. Remember, it has infinitely many antiderivatives.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger i did fix it, but in this setting, everyone will end up with the same one so *the* was not exactly misplaced